# Aligning by ; with dcolumn works only for 1 column

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multicolumn, dcolumn

I have a problem with aligning columns by `;`. Using the dcolumn package I was able to align the first column but when I try align all 4 columns by `;`, like this `\begin{tabular}{r|kkkk}`, it fails with errors. I need to know how to align columns the way I did with the first column in the picture below. Any help is apreciated.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\newcolumntype{k}{D{;}{;}{-1}}
\centering
\caption{Závislosť počtu pozorovaných dát a veľkosti diskretizačných krokov na rýchlosť konvergercie z hľadiska počtu iterácií a čase trvania algoritmu.}
\begin{tabular}{r|kccc}
  \toprule                        
      \multicolumn{5}{c}{\qquad \qquad Diskretizačný krok} \\
  \hline \noalign{\smallskip}
 T(čas) & $1$ & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{4}$ & $\frac{1}{8}$ \\
  \noalign{\smallskip}
  \hline
  \noalign{\smallskip}   
 100 &  500; 498s & 221; 229s & 181; 216s & 29; 44s\\
 250 & 500; 541s & 115; 142s & 43; 65s & 18; 40s \\
 500 & 500; 573s & 144; 206s & 82; 155s & 24; 72s\\
 1 000 & 500; 653s & 108; 208s & 31; 90s & 16; 80s\\
 10 000 & 500; 2 092s & 101; 1 090s & 30; 651s & 16; 718s\\
 100 000 & 500; 16 255s & 89; 8 814s & 30; 5 781s & 16; 6 631s \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{table:itacas}
\end{table}
```

[image: table in latex]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Please make your example into a _complete_ document so people can reproduce the problem without having to guess needed packages (you are using at least booktabs and float in addition to dcolumn I would guess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `$\frac{1}{2}$` in a `D` column if you change that column type to a dcolumn package column then you need to change the headings back to `c` with

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\frac{1}{2}$}
```